# AWS DMS swap files consumes all the space

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms, dms

I'm migrating many databases but I have seen my databases with a size bigger than 50GB fails in the CDC after some time due to a lack of storage.

I'm using a replication instance class `dms.r5.large` and everything runs smoothly until the full-load is completed.
When the CDC starts I got logs messages likes these:

```
D:  There are 188 swap files of total size 93156 Mb. Left to process 188 of size 93156 Mb
```

But swap files are never dropped the instance keeps accumulating swap files and eventually the instance runs out of storage.
A thing to notice is my swap usage in the monitoring metrics is near to zero.

I have already tried with a `dms.r5.xlarge` and the issue was the same, which makes me think memory is not a problem.

Do you know what could be the cause of this behavior?
Is there a way to debug this?

Thank you!

**More useful data:**
Replication instance class: `dms.r5.large`, I have tried with `dms.r5.xlarge`.
`40GB` of storage, I have tried with `300GB` but eventually the CDC phase consume all the storage.
The database to migrate is about `80GB`.
Task settings:

```
{
    "TargetMetadata": {
        "TargetSchema": "",
        "SupportLobs": true,
        "FullLobMode": false,
        "LobChunkSize": 0,
        "LimitedSizeLobMode": true,
        "LobMaxSize": 32,
        "InlineLobMaxSize": 0,
        "LoadMaxFileSize": 0,
        "ParallelLoadThreads": 0,
        "ParallelLoadBufferSize": 0,
        "BatchApplyEnabled": false,
        "TaskRecoveryTableEnabled": false,
        "ParallelLoadQueuesPerThread": 0,
        "ParallelApplyThreads": 0,
        "ParallelApplyBufferSize": 0,
        "ParallelApplyQueuesPerThread": 0
    },
    "FullLoadSettings": {
        "TargetTablePrepMode": "DROP_AND_CREATE",
        "CreatePkAfterFullLoad": false,
        "StopTaskCachedChangesApplied": false,
        "StopTaskCachedChangesNotApplied": false,
        "MaxFullLoadSubTasks": 8,
        "TransactionConsistencyTimeout": 600,
        "CommitRate": 10000
    },
    "Logging": {
        "EnableLogging": true,
        "LogComponents": [{
            "Id": "SOURCE_UNLOAD",
            "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
        },{
            "Id": "SOURCE_CAPTURE",
            "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
        },{
            "Id": "TARGET_LOAD",
            "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
        },{
            "Id": "TARGET_APPLY",
            "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_INFO"
        },{
            "Id": "TASK_MANAGER",
            "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEBUG"
        }]
    },
    "ControlTablesSettings": {
        "historyTimeslotInMinutes": 5,
        "ControlSchema": "",
        "HistoryTimeslotInMinutes": 5,
        "HistoryTableEnabled": false,
        "SuspendedTablesTableEnabled": false,
        "StatusTableEnabled": false
    },
    "StreamBufferSettings": {
        "StreamBufferCount": 3,
        "StreamBufferSizeInMB": 8,
        "CtrlStreamBufferSizeInMB": 5
    },
    "ChangeProcessingDdlHandlingPolicy": {
        "HandleSourceTableDropped": true,
        "HandleSourceTableTruncated": true,
        "HandleSourceTableAltered": true
    },
    "ErrorBehavior": {
        "DataErrorPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "DataTruncationErrorPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "DataErrorEscalationPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE",
        "DataErrorEscalationCount": 0,
        "TableErrorPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE",
        "TableErrorEscalationPolicy": "STOP_TASK",
        "TableErrorEscalationCount": 0,
        "RecoverableErrorCount": -1,
        "RecoverableErrorInterval": 5,
        "RecoverableErrorThrottling": true,
        "RecoverableErrorThrottlingMax": 1800,
        "RecoverableErrorStopRetryAfterThrottlingMax": false,
        "ApplyErrorDeletePolicy": "IGNORE_RECORD",
        "ApplyErrorInsertPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "ApplyErrorUpdatePolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "ApplyErrorEscalationPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "ApplyErrorEscalationCount": 0,
        "ApplyErrorFailOnTruncationDdl": false,
        "FullLoadIgnoreConflicts": true,
        "FailOnTransactionConsistencyBreached": false,
        "FailOnNoTablesCaptured": false
    },
    "ChangeProcessingTuning": {
        "BatchApplyPreserveTransaction": true,
        "BatchApplyTimeoutMin": 1,
        "BatchApplyTimeoutMax": 30,
        "BatchApplyMemoryLimit": 500,
        "BatchSplitSize": 0,
        "MinTransactionSize": 1000,
        "CommitTimeout": 1,
        "MemoryLimitTotal": 1024,
        "MemoryKeepTime": 60,
        "StatementCacheSize": 50
    },
    "ValidationSettings": {
        "EnableValidation": true,
        "ValidationMode": "ROW_LEVEL",
        "ThreadCount": 5,
        "PartitionSize": 10000,
        "FailureMaxCount": 10000,
        "RecordFailureDelayInMinutes": 5,
        "RecordSuspendDelayInMinutes": 30,
        "MaxKeyColumnSize": 8096,
        "TableFailureMaxCount": 1000,
        "ValidationOnly": false,
        "HandleCollationDiff": false,
        "RecordFailureDelayLimitInMinutes": 0,
        "SkipLobColumns": false,
        "ValidationPartialLobSize": 0,
        "ValidationQueryCdcDelaySeconds": 0
    },
    "PostProcessingRules": null,
    "CharacterSetSettings": null,
    "LoopbackPreventionSettings": null,
    "BeforeImageSettings": null
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Issues were due to a **high target latency**, the root cause was the structure of the database tables.

Tables with significant amount of records had a lack of `primary keys` or `unique identifiers` that causes a **full-table scans**, changes were not applied and then saved in the replication instance storage.

Eventually the instance will run out of storage.

To fix this you should run a pre migration assessment to check if you database applies for DMS migration.

Another way to fix this is add an extra column in the migration to create a unique key and remove it after the migration.

Answer (score 0):

You should increase configuration in Task settings as well. Like -

- MemoryLimitTotal
- BatchApplyMemoryLimit